# Calculate average rating

Tags: average, rating

Can any one tell me how to calculate rating average?

Comment: Is there any difference between rating average and ordinary average?

Comment: I really don't think that a programmer can ask such a question. It is like asking "How do I vote" as a president.

Comment: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Answer (score 13):

I interpret *rating average* as the *average of a set of ratings*.

In that case you simply compute

```
                 sum_of_all_ratings
rating_average = ------------------
                  number_of_ratings
```

Comment: Sekar, if this answered your question, I suggest you accept it so we get a closure on this.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend this
example :

Ordinary average : (a+b+c....z)/(number_added_items)

Rating average : (va*a + vb*b + vc*c... +vz*z)/(number_added_items)

In the first case you could say that the weight for each item is 1 as all items have the same weight in the calculation, while in the second case weights differ)

In your case the weight for each rating vote might depend on the voter so let's say a highly rated voter has a ponder for 3 his vote while a novice has 1.If 3 novices vote for an answer the rating of that answer will be  (1*1+1*1+1*1)/(3) = 1 while if 2 high voters and a novice vote for an answer the average will be 3*1+3*1+1*1/3 = 2.33.

Does this answer your question? otherwise please be more explicit.

Comment: Thanks, catalin Marin!, i think the second case won't help me, b'coz i dont have different value for novoice & skilled one. so each have only one value pervote. so the first case suits me. Thanks once again...